# JQuery addClass for CSS subclass

Tags: jquery, addclass

This feels somewhat embarrassing to ask because I feel like I should know the answer.  How do you add a CSS subclass to a DIV with JQuery.

So my CSS is =

```
.class1 .subclass1 {

  width: 10px;
  heigh: 10px;

}
```

How do I add the subClass1 to a DIV?  e.g.

```
$("#foo").addClass( ????? )
```

I tried doing addClass( class1 subclass1), but that doesn't work as I believe jquery is expecting subclass1 to be an independent class.  Of course, if I get rid of the subclass notion and just call the class "class1-subclass1" in my CSS, then of course it works.

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: The CSS rule you show requires ***2 different*** elements, that means 2 classes may not belong to the same element.

Comment: Quite confusing..! can you post the expected markup..?

Comment: Adding the so-called *subclass* in this case may mean exactly adding some child element (having class `subclass1`) to your div.

Comment: Not sure what the confusion with the question is.  In CSS you can have sub classes, yes?  So above I have the CSS where .subclass1 is the sub class of class1.  So normally, in jquery if I didn't have a subclass and I was going to do an addClass on a DIV with id = "foo", I would do $("#foo").addClass("class1").  All I am asking is how do I specify the subclass in the addClass?  I tried $("#foo).addClass("class1 subclass1").  That didn't work because I think jquery is expecting 'subclass1' to be an independent class.  So how do I do addClass on a subClass?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain how css class chaining works...

If you write (with a blank space between 2 classes):

```
.class1 .subclass1{
  width: 10px;
  heigh: 10px;
}
```

It applies to all "decendents" of a `<div id="foo" class="class">` having a class .subclass1 .
For this your html must be formatted something like this:

```
<div id="foo" class="class1">
  <div class="subclass1">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

If you want both .class1 and .subclass1 to be applied to the same `<div>` and you html is something like this:

```
<div class="class1 subclass1">
  <div class="">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Your css must be: (without the blank space between the 2 classes)

```
.class1.subclass1{
      width: 10px;
      heigh: 10px;
    }
```

OR....

```
.class1{
         <some code>
        }
.subclass1{
          width: 10px;
          heigh: 10px;
        }
```

Now to answer your question:
For JS you are actually adding 2 different classes. Therefore you must call the addClass method twice:

```
$("#foo").addClass('class');
$("#foo").addClass('subclass');
```

It's up to you to decide where to the apply the classes.